# Can I counter Thrun by flashing Lodestone Golem? Can I counter anything by flashing Lodestone Golem?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My opponent has 4 untapped forests and taps all their land to cast [Thrun](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=214050). 
I respond by using [Quicksilver Amulet](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=237006)  to put [Lodestone Golem](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=191557) into play. Since Thrun now costs an extra `1` that my opponent does not have, would it be countered? Would the result be any different if the spell being cast did not have Thrun's ability (perhaps it was a [Cudgel Troll](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=221895) instead)?

For Thrun, it seems like this might be a case of "*countered by game rules*" but it doesn't say "*can't be countered by spells or abilities*" it just says "*can't be countered.*"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Putting Lodestone Golem onto the battlefield in response to a creature spell has no effect on that creature spell whatsoever.

Lodestone Golem's ability adds an additional cost that is applied while casting spells. Once a player has finished casting a spell by paying the costs for that spell, any new cost modifications don't affect it.

Comment: The relevant rules: 

*601.2. [...] To cast a spell, a player follows the steps listed below, in order. [...]*

*601.2f The player determines the total cost of the spell. [...] Once the total cost is determined, any effects that directly affect the total cost are applied. Then the resulting total cost becomes “locked in.” If effects would change the total cost after this time, they have no effect.*